# What type of work that you were not allowed to do by the senior sysadmin?

Tags: untagged

For the junior sysadmin:

> What type of work that you were not allowed to do by the senior sysadmin?

Comment: You are not allowed to do anything that will cost *me* my job. :)

Comment: jscott pretty much hit it on the head with his comment.  I've zotted this as "Too Localized" only because what I might allow at one company would be different from what I'd allow elsewhere -- It depends on the environment and how sensitive certain areas are.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about specifics, mostly because it's been a while since I was a "junior sysadmin", but it's probably fair to say that as I've progressed up the ladder I've become less involved in day to day menial tasks connected with what IT needs to be doing to support the business and more involved in deciding what those menial tasks are and what IT *should* be doing to support the business.

To give one example: When I started work in IT as a "Mainframe Operator" the low level job that I started in largely consisted of loading tapes and keeping the printer going. Tomorrow I'm going to a conference that helps decide the future of Internet connectivity for educational establishments in the UK. And I'm still a "senior engineer/sysadmin" rather than a "manager".

Answer (score 0):

My question to you is: What kind of company are we talking about? In my line of duty, the junior worker does mostly menial tasks to begin with, and then more and more tasks with slightly more enhanced complexities.

My advice is: If you decide to do something: Listen good, and absorb anything that is said to you when you get assignments.